# Polymorphic belongs_to must have exactly one of primary type within scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, polymorphic-associations

I have a Rails app with a `Dancer` model that has and belongs to many `Groups` via a join table `DancerGroup`. This join table is also used to assign a type of packaging through a polymorphic association. `Package` or `PackageAddon` can be access via `packaging_type` and `packaging_id` in the `DancerGroup` model.

A given Dancer can only have one `Package` as a primary, and must select from `PackageAddon`s associated with the primary `Package`. I've tried to limit this using JavaScript on the forms, but lately there have been some failures and sometimes a dancer is saved with 2 or 0 `Package`s which break my forms. So I'm trying to come up with a validation that limits how many `Package`s can belong to a `Dancer`.

So far I have this:

```rb
belongs_to :packaging
           polymorphic: true,
           optional: true

validates :packaging_id, numericality: { greater_than: 0,
                                         allow_blank: true }

validates :packaging_type, uniqueness: ( packaging_type == "Package" ),
                           inclusion: { in: %w(Package PackageAddon) },
                           scope: :dancer_id,
                           allow_blank: true
```

Which if it works would allow no more than one `Package` per dancer, but would still allow no `Packages` with any number of `PackageAddon`s.

I've also tried putting this custom validation in the `Dancer` model:

```rb
def packaging_arrangement
  if self.preorder.stage_before_type_cast > 3 # enum stage limiter
    if dancer_groups.where(:packaging_type => "Package").count != 1
      errors.add(:dancer, "must have one primary package")
    end 
  end 
end
```

But it only triggers if the `DancerGroup` record is already saved.

Comment: I'm having trouble following along. If possible, can you post your stripped-down model definitions with just the relevant relationships and validations and then an example from ./bin/rails console where you demonstrate the issue?

Comment: I don't know how I lost you, nor do I understand your request.

Comment: Its a pretty straight forward request. Include the relevant models in the question  as a minimal example of the assocations. Programmers are good at reading code, not vague descriptions of it.

Comment: Also agree that if you share the model definitions; BTW: just a comment and I don't know which database you use. But have you ever considered to also enforce your DB using a constraint or check constraint?